# saving general purpose registers in switch_to() in linux 2.6

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, low-level, context-switch

I saw the code of `switch_to` in the article "Evolution of the x86 context switch in Linux" in the link https://www.maizure.org/projects/evolution_x86_context_switch_linux/

Most versions of `switch_to` only save/restore ESP/RSP and/or EBP/RBP, not other call-preserved registers in the inline asm.  But the Linux 2.2.0 version *does* save them in this function, because it uses software context switching instead of relying on hardware TSS stuff.  Later Linux versions still do software context switching, but don't have these push / pop instructions.

Are the registers are saved in other function (maybe in the `schedule()` function)?  Or is there no need to save these registers in the kernel context?

(I know that those registers of the user context are saved in the kernel stack when the system enters kernel mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux versions before 2.2.0 use hardware task switching, where the TSS saves/restores registers for you.  That's what the `"ljmp %0\n\t"` is doing.  (`ljmp` is AT&T syntax for a far jmp, presumably to a task gate).  I'm not really familiar with hardware TSS stuff because it's not very relevant; it's still used in modern kernels for getting RSP pointing to the kernel stack for interrupt handlers, but not for context switching between tasks.

Hardware task switching is slow, so later kernels avoid it.  Linux 2.2 *does* save/restore the call-preserved registers manually, with `push`/`pop` before/after swapping stacks.  EAX, EDX, and ECX are declared as dummy outputs (`"=a" (eax), "=d" (edx), "=c" (ecx)`) so the compiler knows that the old values of those registers are no longer available.

This is a sensible choice because `switch_to` is probably used inside a non-inline function.  The caller will make a function call that *eventually* returns (after running another task for a while) with the call-preserved registers restored, and the call-clobbered registers clobbered, just like a regular function call.  (So compiler code-gen for the function that uses the `switch_to` macro doesn't need to emit save/restore code outside of the inline asm).  If you think about writing a whole context switch function in asm (not *inline* asm), you'd get this clobbering of volatile registers for free because callers expect that.

**So how do later kernels avoid saving/restoring those registers in inline asm?**

Linux 2.4 uses `"=b" (last)` as an output operand, so the compiler has to save/restore EBX in a function that uses this asm.  The asm still saves/restores ESI, EDI, and EBP (as well as ESP).  The text of the article notes this:

> The 2.4 kernel context switch brings a few minor changes: EBX is no longer pushed/popped, but it is now included in the output of the inline assembly. We have a new input argument.

I don't see where they tell the compiler about EAX, ECX, and EDX not surviving, so that's odd.  It might be a bug that they get away with by making the function `noinline` or something?

Linux 2.6 on i386 uses more output operands that get the compiler to handle the save/restore.

But Linux 2.6 for x86-64 introduces the trick that hands off the save/restore to the compiler easily:  **`#define __EXTRA_CLOBBER     ,"rcx","rbx","rdx","r8","r9","r10", "r11","r12","r13","r14","r15"`**

Notice the clobbers declaration: `: "memory", "cc" __EXTRA_CLOBBER`

This tells the compiler that the inline asm destroys all those registers, so the compiler will emit instructions to save/restore these registers at the start/end of whatever function `switch_to` ultimately inlines into.

Telling the compiler that all the registers are destroyed after a context switch solves the same problem as manually saving/restoring them with inline asm.  The compiler will still make a function that obeys the calling convention.

The context-switch swaps to the new task's stack, so the compiler-generated save/restore code is always running with the appropriate stack pointer.  Notice that the explicit push/pop instructions inside the inline asm int Linux 2.2 and 2.4 are before / after everything else.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I don't see a fix in that diff.  There's still no `"=c"` or `"=d"` output or clobber.

Comment: I had so many links open earlier, i provided the wrong one. I'll have to go searching for it gain.

Comment: You can see where 2.6.26-rc1 has one that is fixed: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.26-rc1/source/include/asm-x86/system.h  . The last 2.6.25 still had the bug: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.25.20/source/include/asm-x86/system.h#L30

Comment: If you review the code you'll see there is a _set_base and _set_limit function. Take a look at the memory operands (they are marked as read but they get written to). That occurred all the way up until (and including) the last 2.6.31.14 release. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.31.14/source/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h . IN 2.6.32 it was refactored and the inline assembly for those were removed. The x86-64 _switch_to is bastardized as well with the same clobber issue. It was eventually fixed (from what I can tell) when all that code was refactored

Comment: @MichaelPetch: wow, that's evil without a `"memory"` clobber.  Surprised anyone let that into the kernel.  I knew Linux was sometimes sloppy with `asm`, but this seems worse than most.

Comment: @MichaelPetch in linux 2.6 for x86_64 I saw the EXTREA_CLOBBER you were talking about but I also know that the compiler may choose not to save those registers on the stack and here because it is context switch the compiler must do so but he doesnt know it is a context switch. Does he save them on the stack because all genreal purpose registers are in the clobber list or in output/input and so he understand he must save them on the stack?

Comment: @roycabouly: It doesn't matter what the compiler actually does, just that it knows the registers are effectively trashed when execution leaves the inline asm.  In practice to obey the calling convention, it will save/restore the registers it knows its caller is expecting to be preserved.

Comment: I looked also in the code in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.31.14/source/arch/x86/include/asm/system.h and I saw they tell that eax is not saved because he is being used as the return value of the assembly. Isnt it still has to be saved so the caller function could use the former value?

Comment: @roycabouly: no.  EAX, ECX, and EDX are call-clobbered registers for i386.  But regardless, the compiler takes care of following the calling convention for the whole function that uses the `asm` statement.  What's important for the asm statement is to tell the compiler about *all* registers that it doesn't bother to preserve itself.  The compiler knows what to do.  Try putting an asm statement inside a function yourself on https://godbolt.org/ and look at the asm output.